# Filter one column and count the occurence in the other column

Tags: python, for-loop, lambda, counter

I'm trying to get the highest occurrence in second column(Source IP) by using the 4th column (alert).

**Sample list:**

```
test=[["2019-01-05 03:15:49","192.168.0.15","192.168.0.116:4070","network discover"],
["2019-01-05 03:25:49,"192.168.0.15","192.168.0.1:4070","network discover"],
["2019-01-05 03:35:49","192.168.0.15","192.168.0.116:4070","network discover"],
["2019-01-05 03:55:49,"192.168.0.12","192.168.0.1:4070","network discover"],
["2019-01-05 04:38:13","192.168.0.15","192.168.0.41:445","ETERNALBLUE tool"],
["2019-01-05 05:28:13","192.168.0.12","192.168.0.39:445","ETERNALBLUE tool"]]
```

**Desired Output**

> network discover, 192.168.0.15 = 3
>
> network discovery, 192.168.0.12 = 1
>
> ETERNALBLUE tool, 192.168.0.15 = 1
>
> ETERNALBLUE tool, 192.168.0.12 = 1

Comment: Hey :) What's your question actually? Where in achieving your desired output did you get stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

test=[["2019-01-05 03:15:49","192.168.0.15","192.168.0.116:4070","network discover"],
["2019-01-05 03:25:49","192.168.0.15","192.168.0.1:4070","network discover"],
["2019-01-05 03:35:49","192.168.0.15","192.168.0.116:4070","network discover"],
["2019-01-05 03:55:49","192.168.0.12","192.168.0.1:4070","network discover"],
["2019-01-05 04:38:13","192.168.0.15","192.168.0.41:445","ETERNALBLUE tool"],
["2019-01-05 05:28:13","192.168.0.12","192.168.0.39:445","ETERNALBLUE tool"]]

result = defaultdict(int)
for i in test:
    result[(i[-1], i[1])] += 1
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {
    ('network discover', '192.168.0.12'): 1, 
    ('ETERNALBLUE tool', '192.168.0.15'): 1, 
    ('ETERNALBLUE tool', '192.168.0.12'): 1, 
    ('network discover', '192.168.0.15'): 3
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
from pprint import pprint

c = Counter((i[-1], i[1]) for i in test)

pprint(c)
```

Output:

```
Counter({('network discover', '192.168.0.15'): 3,
         ('network discover', '192.168.0.12'): 1,
         ('ETERNALBLUE tool', '192.168.0.15'): 1,
         ('ETERNALBLUE tool', '192.168.0.12'): 1})
```